# How to find a leaf in a hierachy of Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

> .Net 3.5 C# question:

If I have a Windows Forms app with several forms displayed concurrently, and say form 'A' is the parent of form 'B', how can I tell if form 'B' is a leaf in the hierarchy (ie there are no displayed forms which have 'B' as a parent)?

The hierarchy is usually more complex than that and I need to close the open forms in reverse order (leaves first), so I need to identify which have no child forms.

I have tried this

```
foreach (Form f in topLevelForm.OwnedForms)
{
    bool isLeaf = f.Controls.OfType<Form>().FirstOrDefault() == null;
    if (isLeaf)
    {
        f.Close();
    }
}
```

but that identifies them all as 'leaves' even when they obviously are not, and consequently I have no control over the order of closing. The Form class doesn't seem to have a straight forward way of doing this.

Can anyone suggest a way forward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is not an MDI application, try going in reverse order:

```
for (int i = topLevelForm.OwnedForms.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
  topLevelForm.OwnedForms[i].Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Did you mean this.OwnedForms[i].Dispose();, or did you mean  topLevelForm.OwnedForms[i].Dispose(); ?

Comment: Anyhow I changed it to topLevelForm.OwnedForms[i].Dispose(); , and that solves the problem for me.

Comment: @NeilHaughton Yes, I meant `topLevelForm`.  Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, a form is never going to be a child control of another form unless you expressly add it to the Controls collection.  An owned form is an owned form, not a child control.

Assuming that you are making every for in this hierarchy an owned form, you can only use the OwnedForms collection of the owner and the Owner property of the owned form to traverse the relationship.  If the forms you're opening are not owned then there is no relationship to traverse.